# Different behaviour after copying methods

Tags: javascript

I was expecting the same behaviour from getName2 and getName3, but getName3 throws an error (prints 'The Window' in non-strict mode)

```
"use strict";

var name = 'The Window';
var object = {
    name : 'The Object',
    getName: function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
};

object.getName();    // The Object

object.getName2 = object.getName;
object.getName2();    // The Object

(object.getName3 = object.getName)(); // Error: TypeError: this is undefined
```

This code is derived from an example in Chapter 7 of Professional Javascript for Web Developers by N.Zakas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of a function depends on *how it is called*. In your final example, you use a [grouping operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.6) (a pair of parentheses) which returns a reference to the function referred to by `object.getName`. It loses the context of `object`.

When you then invoke that function, since it's lost the context of `object` and you're running in strict mode, the context becomes the global object and `this` is `undefined`. You can force that function to run in the context of `object` by, for example, explicitly binding it to it:

```
(object.getName3 = object.getName).bind(object)(); // The Object
```

Comment: Thanks @James Allardice, but why parentheses don't have the same effect on getName2?


`(object.getName2)();    // The Object`

Comment: Because the `(o.g3 = o.g)` returns the result of the *assignment*, which is a function (with no context). `(o.g2)` returns the function with the context. Consider this: `var x = object.getName; x();`. That's effectively what's happening.

Comment: Ok now I understand, it's the combination of assignment and execution which generates the different behaviour.

The assignment is only passing a function, which doesn't have a context attached to it, the context being provided by object.

At the end, there are not differences between getName2 and getName3.

`// non-strict mode`
`(object.getName3 = object.getName)(); // The Window`
`(object.getName3)(); // The Object`

Thanks!